# Download full Interactive Grid to CSV via Javascript in Oracle APEX

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I have a JS script which downloads Interactive Grid to CSV file in Oracle APEX. The problem is that the report contains multiple pages but JS script download only visible rows on the first page. So for example there is a 20 rows per page. I have 200 pages so in result the CSV file contains only 20 rows from the first page instead of 4000. How can I solve this problem?

Below my script for the CSV download:

```
    var csv = [];
    var rows = document.querySelectorAll("table tr");
    for(var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++){
            var row = [], cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll("td,th");
            for(var j = 1; j < cols.length; j++){
                row.push('"' + cols[j].innerText.trim() + '"');    
            }
            csv.push(row.join(",") + "\n");
    }
    let csvRawData = csv.join('');
```

Comment: Does the solution need to be Javascript?  A client-side Javascript function is only going to be able to see what appears on the page.  The interactive report inherently has the ability to request a CSV export if you enable that-- is there a reason that you don't want to use the built-in functionality?

Comment: @JustinCave in a previous post the user indicated that he wants the values to be enclosed in quotes, which is not done in the default IG download and not configurable

Comment: I would suggest not re-inventing the wheel by writing your own download functionality. Have a look at the pl/sql package "APEX_DATA_EXPORT" ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/22.1/aeapi/APEX_DATA_EXPORT.html)). There are some examples on how to use this package if you google around. Moreover, since this is native functionality, chances of it breaking during upgrades are a lot lower.